# SQLITE3 programming learning in Python

Tags: database, sqlite, error-handling, multiple-columns, helper

I've created a new sql base in pycharm and it gave me the next error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rnicolescu\Desktop\my_program.py", line 619 (line from the pycharm), in 
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Names (id, firstname, surname, phonenumber)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table Names has no column named surname

and the code writen is as follows:

import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect("Phonebook.db") as db:
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Names (
id integer PRIMARY KEY,
firstname text,
surname text,
phonenumber text);""")

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Names (id, firstname, surname, phonenumber)
VALUES ('1', 'Simon', 'Robert', '0725383561')""")
db.commit()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Names (id, firstname, surname, phonenumber)
VALUES ('2', 'Robert', 'Mihai', '0725333698')""")
db.commit()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Names (id, firstname, surname, phonenumber)
VALUES ('3', 'Marc', 'Aurelius', '0122238569')""")
db.commit()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Names (id, firstname, surname, phonenumber)
VALUES ('4', 'Iulian', 'Constantin', '3532644226')""")
db.commit()

db.close()

Where should I look for the error? I can't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Delete the database and rerun.

Comment: i've try this and is the same error